# Javascript Exercise: Remove all the array's elements before the given one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making some practice with Javascript. This exercise from [js.checkio.org](https://js.checkio.org/) asks this:

Not all of the elements are important. What you need to do here is to remove from the array all of the elements before the given one. We have two edge cases here: (1) if a cutting element cannot be found, then the array shouldn't be changed. (2) if the array is empty, then it should remain empty.

Here is my code:

```
function removeAllBefore(array, number) { 
     if (array.length === 0)
         return array;
     for (let element of array)
         if (element === number)
         filtered = array.filter(n => n => number);
             return filtered;
}

console.log(removeAllBefore([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```

I am able to have the new array's values, the problem is with the statement where "if (element !== number) return array", I can't put it in the code without errors and now I am stuck and curious about the solution.

Thanks for all the support 
Carlo

Comment: You have a typo: `n => n => number` should be `n => n === number`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function removeAllBefore (array, number) { 
  const indexOfElement = array.indexOf(number);
  if(indexOfElement !== -1) {
      return array.splice(indexOfElement, array.length - 1);
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(removeAllBefore([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6)); // element not found
console.log(removeAllBefore([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)); // found element
console.log(removeAllBefore([], 6)); // empty array
```

First find the index of the element, then just use [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove elements before this index.

Answer (score 0):

(2) is a bit misleading as special case, as an empty array won't contain the element, and thus returning it unchanged as (1) requires is already what (2) asks for.

Otherwise learn about `indexOf()` and `slice()` for example:

```js
function removeAllBefore(array, number) { 
  var position = array.indexOf(number);
  if(position === -1) // not found
    return array;
  return array.slice(position);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(removeAllBefore([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)));  // original test
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeAllBefore([1, 3, 4, 5], 2)));     // "unchanged" test
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeAllBefore([], 2)));               // empty test
```

(`JSON.stringify()` is added only to show the arrays in one line - they would be printed in a one-element-per-line format otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeAllBefore(array, number) {
    let filtered = [];
    if (array.length === 0) return array;
    for (let element of array) 
    if (element === number)
    array.splice(0, array.indexOf(element))
    filtered = array
    return filtered;
    }
console.log(removeAllBefore([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```

This removes all values preceding the one you have defined, and leaves the rest including the one you have defined
The `splice` function takes 2 arguments, the index you are removing from and the index before the last element to remove: `splice(//from beginning of array, //to index before last element to remove)` ...

And the `indexOf` function gets the index of the value you have defined